# How to upload Image on server using ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am setting headers and body , Using fetch with Post to upload image on server.I am getting the response code 200 but it is not uploading image but rest of the Data is getting uploaded.

Here is the code of body:

```
export default function setRequestBody(imagePath){

    let boundry = "----WebKitFormBoundaryIOASRrUAgzuadr8l";

    let body = new FormData();

    body.append("--"+boundry+"\r\n");
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=imageCaption\r\n\r\n");
    body.append("Caption"+"\r\n");
    body.append("--"+boundry+"\r\n");
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=imageFormKey; filename =iimageName.pngg \r\n");
    body.append("Content-Type: image/png \r\n\r\n");
    body.append({uri : imagePath});
    // appened image Data Here
    body.append("\r\n");
    body.append("--"+boundry+"--\r\n");
    return body

}
```

Please help.What mistake I am making. :(

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native/72998342#72998342

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
let body = new FormData();
body.append('photo', {uri: imagePath,name: 'photo.png',filename :'imageName.png',type: 'image/png'});
body.append('Content-Type', 'image/png');

fetch(Url,{ method: 'POST',headers:{  
     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
     "otherHeader": "foo",
     } , body :body} )
  .then((res) => checkStatus(res))
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => { console.log("response" +JSON.stringify(res)); })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  .done()
```

** filename is optional...

Comment: it gives me error of TypeError: Network request failed any solution?

Comment: I believe `body.append('Content-Type', 'image/png');` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rajeev wtf is checkStatus?

Comment: Want to know how did your imagePath look like, was it 'https://...' or was it like require('../sample.jpeg)? Cause I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Argument of type '{ uri: string; name: string; filename: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.

Comment: what happens if the image is not a png?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is `body.append({uri : imagePath});` because react native JSC does not support File and Blob, so you have to use libraries.

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) has very good support for this, example from its [README.md](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#multipartform-data-example--post-form-data-with-file-and-data)

```
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://www.example.com/upload-form', {
        Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
        otherHeader : "foo",
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    }, [
    // element with property `filename` will be transformed into `file` in form data
    { name : 'avatar', filename : 'avatar.png', data: binaryDataInBase64},
    // custom content type
    { name : 'avatar-png', filename : 'avatar-png.png', type:'image/png', data: binaryDataInBase64},
    // part file from storage
    { name : 'avatar-foo', filename : 'avatar-foo.png', type:'image/foo', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_a_file)},
    // elements without property `filename` will be sent as plain text
    { name : 'name', data : 'user'},
    { name : 'info', data : JSON.stringify({
      mail : 'example@example.com',
      tel : '12345678'
    })},
  ]).then((resp) => {
    // ...
  }).catch((err) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: Using this gives error :
Undefined is an object (evaluating RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir)

Comment: this is a native module, you'll have to link native libraries and recompile the project.

Comment: This actually still works in 2023! I spend 8 hours on formData not working on React Native for Android. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to Upload the Image on server in React Native:

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('image[]', {
          name: 'test.' + imageurl?.type?.substr(6),
          type: imageurl?.type,
          uri:
            Platform.OS !== 'android'
              ? 'file://' + imageurl?.uri
              : imageurl?.uri,
        });
const res = await axios.post(url, formdata, {
        headers: {
          Accept: '*/*',
          'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
```

Comment: Where is append coming from in JS?

Answer (score 0):

//First Install and import Image-piker
//install

```
npm i react-native-image-picker
```

//import

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
```

//then

```
const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
const [Type,setType]=React.useState('')
```

//Get the image

```
const pickImage = async () => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
  });

  console.log(result);

  if (!result.cancelled) {
      // extract the filetype
   setType(result.uri.substring(result.uri.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
 setImage(result.uri);
 
  }
};
```

//show image return

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Ecolher Foto" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} />}
    </View>
```

//UpLoad Image

```
var validatinoApi ='https://seusite.com/OOP/';
var headers={
 'Accept':'application/json',
 "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
 'crossDomain': 'true',
 'Host': 'https://seusite.com/OOP/',
 'Origin': 'https://origem.com',
 
  };
 /*'crossDomain': 'true',*/
 var Data={
  image:image,
  namefoto: `photo.${namefoto}`,
  type: `image/${Type}`

 };

 fetch(validatinoApi,
  {
   method:'POST',
   headers:headers,
   body:JSON.stringify(Data)
 }).then((response)=>response.json())
   .then((response)=>{
     if(response.statusCode==200){
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("attachment", {
      uri: imageUri,
      name: "myimage.jpg",
       filename:"imageFile"
      type: "image/jpg",
    });

    const response = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://139.89.69.142:5000/api/attachments",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      data: formData,
    });
```

The "attachment" in formData.append() should be replaced with that provided by the backend dev or that the API requires.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @Ven Jest's answer, if you want to upload multiple images I've made a minimal working example:

`App.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Image, ScrollView, View } from "react-native";
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";


async function add_images(setImages) {

  const images = await launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'photo', selectionLimit: 0 });

  if (images.didCancel)
    return

  setImages(val => {
    let copy_val = [...val]

    images.assets.forEach((item) => {
      copy_val.push({ uri: item.uri, filename: item.fileName })
    })

    return copy_val
  });

}

async function upload_images(images) {

  let data = []
  images.forEach((item, index) => {
    data.push({ name: 'images_data', filename: item.filename, data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(item.uri) })
  })

  // you may have to use another route instead of localhost
  RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'localhost:3000/upload_images', { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, data);
}

export default function App() {

  const [images, setImages] = useState([]) // array of URIs
  
  return (<>

    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', marginVertical: 50 }}>
      <Button title="Add Images" onPress={() => { add_images(setImages) }} />
      <Button title="Clear Images" onPress={() => { setImages([]) }} />
      <Button title="Upload Images" onPress={() => { upload_images(images) }} />
    </View>

    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      {
        images.map((item, index) => {
          return (<Image key={index} style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }} source={{ uri: item.uri }} />)
        })
      }
    </ScrollView>

  </>)
}
```

`Node.js`

```
// import fs from 'fs';
import multer from "multer";
import express from 'express';
const server = express();

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

server.post('/upload_images', upload.array('images_data'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    
    // req.files.forEach(item => {
    //     fs.renameSync(item.path, item.destination + item.originalname)
    // })
});

const PORT = 3000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening at ${PORT} ...`);
});
```

For reference, the server `console.log` is as such:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     fieldname: 'images_data',
>     originalname: 'image_1.jpg',
>     encoding: '7bit',
>     mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
>     destination: 'uploads/',
>     filename: '8466672ac610519ce55f23af6926c9f',
>     path: 'uploads/8466672ac610519ce55f23af6926c9f',
>     size: 86475
>   },
>   {
>     fieldname: 'images_data',
>     originalname: 'image_2.jpg',
>     encoding: '7bit',
>     mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
>     destination: 'uploads/',
>     filename: 'd8bf4a571ef544542e98aa3aeddbdeb2',
>     path: 'uploads/d8bf4a571ef544542e98aa3aeddbdeb2',
>     size: 79512
>   },
>   {
>     fieldname: 'images_data',
>     originalname: 'image_3.jpg',
>     encoding: '7bit',
>     mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
>     destination: 'uploads/',
>     filename: '04bf7f37791a20023bca5e4d90e2e7b67',
>     path: 'uploads/04bf7f37791a20023bca5e4d90e2e7b67',
>     size: 2271
>   }
> ]
> ```

I was stuck on this for quite a while, hope this helps :)