# React Native - Upload Multiple Image Files in a Single Call

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am referring to this post on react native image upload to server: [How to upload Image on server using ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691379/how-to-upload-image-on-server-using-reactnative)

Other than workaround of calling fetch multiple times for multiple image files upload (looping through the files), I was wondering how to upload multiple of image files by just calling fetch once? Could someone provide a simple example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have similar issue and I have it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423018/upload-multiple-photos-error-one-of-the-sources-for-assign-has-an-enumerable-ke

Comment: Actually I have implemented another way for multiple file upload because I have to upload 1000+ images to server but if in your case if its 1-10 then you can use formdata request and server will handle it but if number of images increased beyond that then you can use queue and upload images one by one. Here you can find deme for queue if you have more number of images : https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-upload-images-queue