# Importing/Exporting file in React-Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, export

We have a js file which we want to save via a button into txt/json and make it exportable. Also when we press that button to save the file, to prop a box where we can choose where the file is gonna be saved. Furthermore we want to be able to import thet file later.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think u may find a solution here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native

Comment: I use local database (SQLite) no server and no requests