# React-Native upload file with `fetch` not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to upload a file using `fetch` module in React-Native.
Here is my code:

```js
 let data = new FormData()
    selfyImg.type = 'image/jpg'
    data.append('img', selfyImg)

    try {

        console.log(0);

        let response = await fetch(
            'https://...',
            {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'x-user-Token': XUserToken
                },
                body: data
            }
        )

        console.log(1);
        
        let status = response.status
        response = await response.json()
        console.log(response)
        return { status: status, msg: response.msg, fa: response.fa }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
```

the `selfyImg` is like following:

```
{
   "data": '...' , "fileName": "20200907_163736.jpg", "fileSize": 26590, "height": 251, "isVertical": true, "originalRotation": 0, "path": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/20200907_163736.jpg", "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "content://media/external/images/media/54219", "width": 296}
}
```

I have added some logs for debugging. As the output, `console.log(1)` is not reachable and the process freezes in `await fetch()` block.

The size of the specified file is not large so it shouldn't be the size problem.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file to server using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native)

Comment: Side note: The `[]` in `['x-user-Token']: XUserToken` are unnecessary. They don't change what properties the object has. Just `'x-user-Token': XUserToken` is all you need.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Thanks. I updated but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: A made a video about this, maybe it can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79WtnkL_XsM

Comment: @M.reza - Right, that's why it was a "side note."

Comment: @TsvetanGanev. Thanks. I have searched as much I could but the issue is not logical.