# Uploading file in react native Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, file, permissions

I'm making my android app with react native.

I want to make an upload(file, image) to my api server.

I searched in google, but I have some question.

The upload Flow what I thought is like below.

**1. GET ACCESS TO LOCAL STORAGE**

**2. IF PERMISSION GRANTED, CLICK BUTTON AND MAKE POPUP**

**3. SELECT THE FILE/IMAGE AND GET URI**

**4. UPLOAD FILE WITH AXIOS**

Am I thinking wrong? Is there a library to make it easier? Thank you

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native/72998342#72998342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) . it will ask for permission and you can take picture from camera or select image from gallery

if you want file other than image you can use [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker)

t**hen upload file using axios**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. and i was using Axios for network calls after a long research, I get to know that Axios with multipart form data along with react native has some issue. and found it working with basic fetch function.