# How to upload images to server with multipart format in react native

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, multipart

I am new to react native. I want to upload images to server in react native. And I want to upload it in multipart format. so pleas help me. is it possible to upload images to server in multipart format is yes then How. I check and search lots of stuff on google But I did not find any single answer of uploading images to server in multipart. please help. thanks.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124650/1435722

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file to server using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a request **using FormData** class to upload images to a server in multipart.

for example:

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('KEY1', VALUE1);
formData.append('KEY2', VALUE2);
formData.append('upload_pancard', 
  {
    uri: pancardImage.uri,
    name: 'pancardImage.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg'
  }
);
formData.append('upload_aadhar', 
    {
        uri: upload_aadhar.uri,
        name: 'upload_aadhar.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg'
    }
);
formData.append('upload_aadhar_second', 
    {
        uri: upload_aadhar_second.uri,
        name: 'upload_aadhar_second.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg'
    }
);
formData.append('digital_signature', 
    {
        uri: digital_signature.uri,
        name: 'digital_signature.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpg'
    }
);
```

if you are supposed to *upload multiple images* then pass the array in the formData.append() to upload multiple images.

Comment: what is meaning of third formData.append

Comment: Why third formData.append different from above two

Comment: And how do I send it in body to API

Comment: @SohilShaikh it is not different to append the value in the formData it is based on which type of value you are supposed to send to the server as here I am sending two string values with KEY1, and KEY2 and at the third I am sending image object to the server

Comment: what if i want to send 4 images

Comment: then, send an array of image objects in value

Comment: But How please edit your code. for uploading 4 images

Comment: I have different keys for 4 images like this = > for pancard image - $_FILES['upload_pancard']
for aadhar 1st image - $_FILES['upload_aadhar']
for aadhar 2nd image - $_FILES['upload_aadhar_second']
for digital signature image - $_FILES['digital_signature']

Comment: @SohilShaikh Check out the updated answer

Comment: AND how to pass in API body like this ?? = >  body: JSON.stringify([{ formData}])

Comment: No, If you have to pass the multipart/formData then you directly can pass in the body without JSON.stringify. like body: formData

Comment: okok thanku so mush for helping me if I have any issue further I will ask you question please Book mark IT please . again thanku so much

Comment: JIgnest Mayani please check my code = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382654/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-data-not-sending-or-uploading-to-server-with-multipa