# Get error when try to uplaod PDF file to server in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I take PDF file from Phone Gallery and upload to server. but when I upload it to server. I get a Error
"[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']".

my code Is:

````
  ```  const UploadCV= async()=>{ //Take pdf file from Phone.
      try {
        
        const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
          type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
        });
        setResume(res.uri)
       
        Alert.alert('Congrulation!!',"Your CV has been Successfuly Uploaded")
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.bs.current.snapTo(1);
        }, 2000);
      
       
      } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
       
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
       //Upload to Server
       const ApplyforJOb= async()=>{ 
         await fetch('https://thejoblocator.co.uk/api/RestApplyJob',{
           method:'post',
           headers:{
             'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream',
           },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              job_id:jobid,
              description:description,
              resume :resume                  
            })
         }).then(res=>res.json())
           .then(data=>{
             console.log("coming data", data)
           }).catch(err=>{
             console.log("Apply Job Error", err)
           })
       }```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file to server using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native)

Comment: @lan Kemp No sir this is not working in mycase

Answer (score 1):

You are not uploading any files
Your error is saying that your json at body is not correct

The pdf file uri is link to assets in phone not the file and you can't upload a file in json like this ,you can either make at blob and embed it like a string json and then upload or you can upload view form data
Please check
[How to upload file to server using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native)

Comment: Sir this path is Ok or not  ?content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A27