# Upload a file from react native image picker to server

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, react-native

can someone tell me what i m doing wrong i keep getting error 400 bad request, i can't seem to figure out how to send the image i tried to send the path, the filename and the mime but it's not working this is my request:

```js
  const [image,setImage]=useState(null)
  const[filename,setFileName]=useState(null)
  const sendpic=async ()=>{
    await ImagePicker.openCamera({
      mediaType:'photo',
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: false,
    }).then(image => {
      setImage(image['path']);
    const paths=image['path']
   
    const filename=paths.substring(paths.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    setFileName(filename);
  console.log(filename)
    console.log(image)
    const data=new FormData();
    data.append('image',filename)
    data.append('title','3aslemajiti')

    const headers={
      Accept:'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    }
    try{
      const response= axios.post('http://192.168.1.19:8000/Sends/',data,{headers:headers})
      alert('yess!!!!!');
    } 
    catch (error) {
      // handle error
      alert(error.message);
    }
  });
  };
```

and this is my model:

```js
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Send(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image=models.ImageField(default ='null')
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

how do i write the request so it is accepted by the server?

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native/72998342#72998342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
               data.append('image', {
                        uri: filename,
                        name: 'test.jpg',
                        type: 'image/jpeg'
                         });
```

Image upload format should be this and please check file url should be correct.

"uri": "file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33198C8D-55D3-4555-B9B5-DC1A61761AAF/data/Containers/Data/Application/B5067299-1CD2-4000-8935-59B59ED447F6/tmp/871EB6D5-2408-4A10-8DE7-EE52B1855ECD.jpg"

this is url for image. it should be like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , this worked

Answer (score 4):

```
 const data = new FormData();
  
  data.append("uploadFile", {
    name: filename,
    type: filetype,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android"
        ? fileuri
        : fileuri.replace("file://", "")
  });
  var url = uploadDoc

  axios.post(url, data, {headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: authToken

  }})
  .then((res) => {
   
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   
  })
```