# How to upload image to server with image picker react native

Tags: react-native, image, file-upload

I want to upload image and upload to server. how can i get a file and can read in server?

```
const takePhotoFromLibraryProfile = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      cropping: true,
    }).then(image => {
      setImageProfile(image.path);
    });
  };
```

and this my axios post

```
axios({
      crossDomain: true,
      method: 'post',
      url: 'url',
      data: {
        userId: dataProfile.id,
        pictures: imageProfile,
      },
      validateStatus: false,
    })
      .then((response, status) => {
        console.log(response);
        setSuccessModal(response.status);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // need handling error
      });
  };
```

i got the respon and also false but in develop web can upload the image. Thank you

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native/72998342#72998342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload images to files to web servers, We cannot send it in the data property of Axios or fetch.

To Upload files or image, **we have to convert the data into form data**. And then we can send the form data to the webserver with the help of the Axios or fetch.

For Example:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('userId', dataProfile.id)
formData.append('pictures', {
    uri: user.profilePicture,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'photo.jpg'
})

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: formData,
  })
    .then((response, status) => {
      console.log(response);
      setSuccessModal(response.status);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // need handling error
    });
};
```

Comment: i got an error formData.push is not a function. (In 'formData.push('userId', dataProfile.id)', 'formData.push' is undefined)

Comment: thankyou, must use formData.append and add this on image uri: user.profilePicture,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',