# React Native - URL to Binary. How to send the url in binary form to backend?

Tags: typescript, react-native, filereader, form-data

I have a **Request - Form Data** from Network -> Payload which contains a file (binary) element.

```
Form Data 
file: (binary)
id: 45451683
```

I don't know how to send the request to the backend to upload file.

For example I have "file://var/mobile/..." and I want to convert this to a binary type so I can send the right request to the backend.

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489502/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-react-native

Comment: @AlexWayne no it doesn't, but thanks

Comment: Why not? That first answer shows how to attach a file with only the URI to a request. What about that scenario is different is different than what you are doing? Or if you tried those solution that what about them didn't work for you?

Comment: @AlexWayne I tried it and the conversion to binary type si not working. The file is still being send as uri and not as binary. The request is not successful.